# How do I extract a database schema from a dacpac file?

Tags: sql, azure, dacpac

I was doing a project a few months back using Azure's free trial and my trial ran out.

I was using a database engine server on SQL Server Management Studio and now I can't access the server anymore.

I have a dacpac file though that contains the schema structure of the database of the project I was working on.

How do I create a new database from my dacpac file in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From Sql Server Management Studio, use the Deploy Data-tier Application menu item to open a deployment wizard.

[image: Deploy Data-tier Application]

Answer (score 0):

As joshb said, you can use [Deploy a Data-tier Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/deploy-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-2017).

Deploy a data-tier application (DAC) from a DAC package to an existing instance of the database engine or Azure SQL Database using a wizard or a PowerShell script.

The deployment process registers a DAC instance by storing the DAC definition in the msdb system database (master in SQL Database); creates a database, then populates that database with all the database objects defined in the DAC.

> How do I create a new database from my dacpac file in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

You can reference my steps:

For example, I have a dacpac file:

[image]

**Using `Deploy a data-tier application`:**
[image]

**Select packages:**
[image]

**Update configuration:**
[image]

**Depoly DAC and finished**:
[image]

The new database is created successfully:

[image]

Hope this helps.